# Bootstrap Confirmation box content not updated

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using confirmation box in one of my project and i am having a hard time in getting that as expected in some certain scenarios like using different js files and all

Working Scenario and [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozwkn6zk/)

Scripts:

```
jquery-2.1.0.js
bootstrap.js v 2.3.2
http://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/bootstrap-confirmation.js


<input type="button" id="clickButton" value="Log in"  class="btn btn-default" />
```

My Jquery

```
$("#clickButton").click(function(){
                var x = Math.random();
                $('#clickButton').confirmation('destroy')
                $("#clickButton").confirmation({ title: x });

});
```

Here i am trying to display a random number as the text inside the confirmation popup

Failed Scenario [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gwgp0zt/)

Bootstrap version 3.3.2
Jquery 2.1.3
Same Confirmation JS File

Comment: So other readers are aware this is not buit-in functionality of bootstrap.  This is a add-on that is most likely having an issue (http://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation).

Comment: So It works only with Specific Versions ?

Comment: I didn't look.   But I'll tell you that if you `destroy` you should probably `shows` it because the confirmation is completely gone.